# Postman request - how to get data from endpoint based on API documentation

Tags: api, rest, postman, data-warehouse

I want to retrieve data from a data warehouse that has a web-based API, I need to use an API key for authentication and use the GET / Customers command to retrieve the list of customers data, but when I am using that same thing in postman, it's returning the same documentation page of the data warehouse?

I am new to this any help will be really appreciated.

[image: screenshot from the postman app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL doesn't look valid:

[image]

You need a base URL, endpoint, http method, authentication scheme, and credential or a token etc.

I don't know details about your system and API, so let's see an example:

- base url is `https://stackoverflow.com`; your current base url is `localhost:4444`, is your server running on your machine? If so, it might be correct, but I assumer you're talking about a server running somewhere else, not on your computer
- endpoint (path parameter) is `/questions/69883697`, in your case `/customers`
- http method is `GET` and you find it here in Postman; it also means it will not go into query parameters where you put it:
  [image]
- authentication scheme - your docs mentions an api key that goes into a header called `Authorization`, so you have to set it in Headers, not as a query parameter:
  [image]

Read carefully what's on your screen, Postman uses the same language as your API documentation, so if your doc speaks about headers, you need to go into Headers tab in Postman.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked and I got the first 10 records, can you tell me what Parameter to use to go to the next page because it just displays the first 10 records.

Comment: From your screen, it looks like it should be a query parameter.

Comment: I added that question here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69884951/need-to-go-to-the-next-page-of-data-in-postman
", if you can ,can you please have a look, that might help a lot, thank you