# need to go to the next page of data in postman

Tags: api, rest, postman

I am pretty new to the postman, so I have a data warehouse that has an API that gives me results as 10 records per page, I need to go to the next page but I don't know how to do that, for reference I am adding 2 pics one of the pictures tells me the what are the query params and the other picture shows just first 10 records.
and I have near about 500 records

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks in advance[image: Picture of the question]

[image: Picture of the first 10 records fetched]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`page` is a query parameter, so you go to Params in Postman and add a new query parameter, e.g. to get data for page 2:

[image]